# Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, forms

how to solve this issue :

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

I get this exception when uploading the file to server. The same code works in firefox but i get this exception only in `IE`

What could be the problem. Please help me to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having code to look at, its hard to pin down the exact cause.  I can tell you that exception means that the bytes sent were assumed to be UTF-8 encoded, but the file you are sending, or at least how IE is trying to send it, is not UTF-8 encoded.